# Simple Windows Forms data binding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Let's say I have a String property in my form (and the form does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged). I've also created a BindingSource and set its DataSource to the form. Then I bind a textbox to the String property on my form (indirectly, using the BindingSource).

Question 1: When I change the value in the textbox at runtime, why don't I hit a breakpoint in the setter of the String property? I thought that binding the control to the String property would allow updates in this direction (GUI -> member data) to occur automatically

Question 2: How can I trigger updates in the other direction (member data -> GUI) to occur when something other than the GUI changes the String property? I don't want to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and add NotifyPropertyChanged to the setter. I thought that by using the BindingSource's ResetBindings I could at least trigger this manually

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private String m_blah;
    public String Blah
    { 
        get
        {
            return m_blah;
        }
        set
        {
            m_blah = value;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bindingSource1, "Blah",true,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Blah = "Clicked!";
        this.bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false); //expecting the GUI to update and say "Clicked!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
this.bindingSource1.DataSource = this;
```

I think you forget to assign data source.

Comment: Perfect! The designer used this statement instead of the one you provided:

    this.bindingSource1.DataSource = typeof(binding_test.Form1);

Comment: @user1130698 so is your problem resolved, tick this as the answer to let us know...

Comment: Still wondering about question 2, how to set up automatic updates in the other direction (member data -> GUI) without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. For now, ResetBindings() does allow me to do this manually

Comment: There is now way you can do it (at least that I know), ResetBinding - for manual update, INotifyPropertyChanged for automatic. I would suggest to use ResetBindings due to more controlable nature, but it depends on what do you want to do and how to work with your entities.